# Getting ClassNotFoundException on standard PMD cyclomatic complexity plug-in

Tags: java, static-analysis, pmd

I'm using PMD version 6.20.0 on Windows 10, and I'm attempting to use the cyclomatic complexity plug-in on what I would consider simple Java code just to see if things work.  I have a single .java file, CCExample.java, with the code as follows (provided just so everyone can see the source file I'm using, versus asking for comments on the below code which I know is inefficient and only for purposes of an example in an engineering talk I'm giving):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class CCExample
{
    public static String reduceString(String s, int index)
    {
        int lastIndex = s.length() - 1;

        if (s.length() == 0)
        {
            return "Empty String";
        }
        else if (index >= lastIndex)
        {
            if (isReduced(s, 0))
            {
                return s;
            }
            else
            {
                return reduceString(s, 0);
            }
        }
        else if (s.charAt(index) == s.charAt(index + 1))
        {
            if (index + 1 < lastIndex)
            {
                return reduceString(s.substring(0, index) + s.substring(index + 2, s.length()), index);
            }
            else
            {
                return reduceString(s.substring(0, index), index);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return reduceString(s, index + 1);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isReduced(String s, int index)
    {
        int lastIndex = s.length() - 1;

        if (index == lastIndex || s.length() == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (s.charAt(index) != s.charAt(index + 1))
        {
            return isReduced(s, index + 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        if (args.length != 1)
        {
            System.out.println("Usage: java CCExample <string>");
        }
        else
        {
            final String s = args[0];
            System.out.println(reduceString(s, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

With this above single .java file I run the following PMD command:

```
pmd -d CCExample.java -debug -R category/java/design.xml/CyclomaticComplexity -f text
```

In the debug log I get the following:

```
Jan 15, 2020 2:35:58 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.RulesetsFactoryUtils printRuleNamesInDebug
FINER: Loaded rule CyclomaticComplexity
Jan 15, 2020 2:35:58 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.processor.PmdRunnable call
FINE: Processing C:\Temp\CCExample.java
Jan 15, 2020 2:35:58 PM net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver visit
FINE: Could not find class CCExample, due to: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CCExample
```

What am I doing wrong that it cannot find class CCExample?  Some .java files I have I get a cyclomatic complexity numbers, others I get the above error.  Is there some formatting I'm not doing correctly?

Comment: If you use -f xml you will be able to get a full stacktrace, with that, you should open an issue directly at PMD https://github.com/pmd/pmd/

Comment: Thanks, I'll use -f xml and take this up with PMD directly.  In the meantime I was able to use lizard, another cyclomatic complexity parser that works on Java, and that is enough for my talk tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Posted this issue to PMD and was told this was by design.  The particular plug-in by default does not show complexity information under 10, my code sample was too simple.  The ClassNotFoundException can also be ignored.